# link to webform based on specific content selection

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

This maybe a basic question.....

I am creating a website that features video and photo content. I need a button that i want to include with a video that will open a webform so the viewer of the video can request the download link for that video.

By clicking the request button, I want the webform that opens to include the video title/webpage that the video is sitting on to be automatically included on the form.

To make it clear my question is... How to include content name or website link in a web form when user clicks on a request button that links to a web form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change form properties, just get form to a variable and change properties:

```
var form  = document.getElementById("someform");
form.method = "post";
form.action = "new URI goes here";
```